# Changing private repository source does not recognize new tags

Tags: git, composer-php

I've been migrating my projects from bitbucket to github now that I can have private repositories for free on github. I migrated a repository this weekend and now I'm running into an issue where my composer file is not recognizing new tags pushed to the repository.

Here is there relevant bits of my composer.json file:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@github.com:myaccount/myrepo.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "myaccount/myproject": "0.*"
    }
```

Whenever I run `composer.phar update`, the latest version of the project when it was on bitbucket is updated which is 0.0.4. Since then, I've added a 0.0.5, 0.0.6, and a 0.1.0 tag to the new version on github.

I've tried to delete the composer.lock file as well as the vendor directory but it still only installs the 0.0.4 tag. I've also tried clearing the composer cache with `composer.phar clearcache` as well as manually deleting the cache in my home directory.

I've also tried installing the project on a server that has never had composer installed. I made the requisite changes there and tried to run composer.phar update but it still only recognizes the 0.0.4 tag.

I have verified that the tags do exist in the github version.

I have also tried manually setting a tag in the composer.json file but when I do that and run `composer.phar update`, the operation never completes. I left it to run overnight and it still had not completed.

I've dumped the output of running `composer.phar install` with no lock or vendor:

```
Reading composer.json of myaccount/myproject (0.0.1)    
Reading composer.json of myaccount/myproject (0.0.2)
Reading composer.json of myaccount/myproject (0.0.3)
Reading composer.json of myaccount/myproject (0.0.4)
Reading composer.json of myaccount/myproject (0.0.5)
Reading composer.json of myaccount/myproject (0.0.6)
Reading composer.json of myaccount/myproject (0.1)
Reading composer.json of myaccount/myproject (0.1.1)
Reading composer.json of myaccount/myproject (master)

  - Installing myaccount/myproject (0.0.4): Cloning be03d13ed4 from cache
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up getting the commit hash for the tag using `git show-ref -s 0.1.1`. I then manually edited the composer.lock file to update both the hash and the version. I then ran `composer.phar install` and it updated to the correct version.

I still do not know why I couldn't convince composer to figure this out itself.